# (&const_object) can be evaluated to address of temporary

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer

I had a discussion with one programmer, and its main point was that the following assertion in `foo` can be passed or not, depending on compiler.

```
#include <cassert> 

const int i = 0 ; 

void foo ( const int& i ) 
{  
    assert( &::i == &i ) ; 
} 

int main ( ) 
{ 
    foo( i ) ; 
}
```

he told me, that (&i) expression can be evaluated to address of some temporary object. 
since i have doubts, i'm here.
how reference to temp can be passed to a function, if in function I can check and do whatever I want with i's and parameter's addresses and expected semantics must be kept.? for example

```
#include <initializer_list>

const int i = 0 ;

bool func ( const int & i ) 
{ 
    return &::i == & i ; 
}

int main ()
{
    const int i = 0 ;
    for ( const int * each : { &::i , &i , } )
         if ( func( * each ) ) break ; // etc
}
```

probably such thing can occur somewhere, but not for this case.
that is how i think, but i cannot get complete proof from standard.

what i have found already (thanks to [npw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp)) :

from [[expr.call#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.call#5)] :

> Where a parameter is of const reference type a temporary object is
>   introduced if needed ([dcl.type], [lex.literal], [lex.string],
>   [dcl.array], [class.temporary])

first four references are not applicable to my case, but fifth gives a hope.

so my question is : does standard give guaranties, that assertion in `foo` will be hold.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first code sample, the `&::i == &i` condition is always true.  A reference of type `const int&` binds directly to an object of type `const int`.  There is no temporary object created.

C++14 [dcl.init.ref]/5:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “ cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “ cv2 T2,” or
>   - [...],
>       then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case  [...]

A type is reference-compatible with itself.

The second example is similar: certainly, initializing a pointer with the address of an object does not create a temporary. It points to the object.

Comment: Yes, `(::i)` is an lvalue designating the object defined by `const int i = 0 ;`. (C++14 expr.prim.general/10 "The result is an lvalue if the member is a
function or a variable", talking about `i` as a member of the global namespace; and parentheses don't change anything)

Comment: @GreenTree I'm not sure what you mean sorry , `(::i)` is an lvalue of type `const int`.  `decltype(::i)` would be `const int`, and `decltype((::i))` would be `const int&` but that's not really relevant here

Comment: yes, i should be more concrete and correct; if somewhere in code address of ::i is required, it's guarantied, that the taken address is the address of ::i and not of some temporary object, yes.?

Comment: Yes, `&x` is the address of `x` for all x